# Calculating scale factor of CanvasView

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, scale

Good evening,

firstly I need to say sorry for my bad english I try to describe my problem as best as I can. So, i'm started again on my little drawing game. The reason why I finished it is because I couldnt handle this problem and I dont want to annoy people here with all my questions.

So as I said i'm making a little "Draw n' Guess" Game. I already solved the synch of Canvas over Firebase, not as I wanted but I solved it. Now I got the problem that the Canvas dousn't fit with every screen and I couldn't figure out how to calculate the matching scale factor.

Every time a room with a canvas got created the screenresolution of the creating device got filled in in Firebase.
If I take another device now with a other screenresolution and join the room the canvas got another size(to big or to small).

I already tried different things to calculate the scale factor.

First was I think just divide the creation size and the actual screen resolution.

Second try was the inverted way.

And the way now is since I my aplication got an actionbar and little ImageView at the bottom to get the screenresolution and subdivide the size of the actionbar and the ImageView with this code.

```
    final int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - getActionBarSize() - (int)(100f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    final int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Which actualy dousnt work too.

I'm sorry for this but did anyone maybe know a solution ?

Thanks for your help!

[image: The gray area is what should be eliminated but it shouldnt be to big either.]

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it in the onLayout of your custom view or in the first draw where getWidth() returns > 0, get the value in any of those and it will be exactly for your view.

Something like:

```
void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {    
if(changed && right > 0) {
     int thisWidth = right - left; 
     // Do your layout things with this size
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question but how can I calculate it in the onLayout ?:/